# Hyperlink not working using knockout. Gives error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, hyperlink

To create a hyperlink I am using the following code.

```
<a data-toggle="tab" data-bind="attr: { href: '../Company/Index/' + IndexID }, text: XYZ"></a>
```

The main purpose of the code is to move back a level from the current one.

The HTML being generated is as follows.

```
<a data-toggle="tab" data-bind="attr: { href: '../Company/Index/' + IndexID }, text: DateTimeStamp" href="../Company/Index/0">XYZ</a>
```

When we try to click on the hyperlink we get the error message

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ../Company/Index/0
    at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery-1.9.0.js:4411)
    at tokenize (jquery-1.9.0.js:5057)
    at select (jquery-1.9.0.js:5439)
    at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery-1.9.0.js:3984)
    at init.find (jquery-1.9.0.js:5553)
    at init (jquery-1.9.0.js:179)
    at jQuery (jquery-1.9.0.js:53)
    at b.show (bootstrap.min.js:9)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:9)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.9.0.js:631)
Sizzle.error @ jquery-1.9.0.js:4411
tokenize @ jquery-1.9.0.js:5057
select @ jquery-1.9.0.js:5439
Sizzle @ jquery-1.9.0.js:3984
find @ jquery-1.9.0.js:5553
init @ jquery-1.9.0.js:179
jQuery @ jquery-1.9.0.js:53
b.show @ bootstrap.min.js:9
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:9
each @ jquery-1.9.0.js:631
each @ jquery-1.9.0.js:253
a.fn.tab @ bootstrap.min.js:9
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:9
dispatch @ jquery-1.9.0.js:3045
elemData.handle @ jquery-1.9.0.js:2721
```

However, when we right click and open it in a new a tab, it works perfectly.

Any helpful pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your purpose with this? Do a full page request or show a bootstrap tab? Because as I can see the problem is that you are mixing urls (which is why opening in new tab works) and bootstrap tabs plugin (which needs a valid selector to decide which tab to show); this functionality intercepts the default behavior of `a` so a request will not happen, but as long as bootstrap is concerned, the value in the `href` is not a valid selector. So the answer depends on whether you want to actually navigate via a http request or use the bootstrap tab the way it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You experience this issue because you define two colliding behaviors in your code. The `data-toggle="tab"` attribute causes Bootstrap's Tab plugin to treat it as a tab trigger, that is, whenever the item is clicked, the associated tab content should be made visible. The `href` attribute, on the other hand, just supplies a regular url in your case.

Now think about this:

- Bootstrap's tab needs a valid *jQuery selector in the href attribute* to figure out what HTML fragment it should make visible,
- But there is an url instead of a selector.

So:

- Right-clicking the element and selecting open in a new tab works, because in this case, the navigation does not get intercepted, the browser simply opens a new tab and causes it to navigate to the selected url, and Bootstrap is not at play here.
- Just clicking it and staying in the same tab does not work, because in this case, the navigation is intercepted by Bootstrap, and it extracts the value of the `href` attribute *and tries to use it as a jQuery selector to make the referenced element visible*. Obviously, because it is an url rather than a selector, it will fail.

So the answer really depends on what you actually want to accomplish.

- Do you want the navigation to occur, and the `data-toggle="tab"` is just an accidental leftover? Fine, just remove this attribute it will work.
- Or do you want to use Bootstrap's tab functionality? Then provide a valid selector instead of an url.

My guess is that the second option was your goal, and if I am not mistaken, the `href` is there because you wanted to use it as a url for an Ajax request, and load the tab's content on-demand. If this is right, the `href` attribute won't help you, you should bind the click event to a method of your viewmodel that does the initialization (that is, populating itself with data from the server). Then you can pass the url of the ajax request to make as described [here, the code block just above 'Note 3'](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html).

Comment: Oh. My mistake. Works fine now. Thanks for the explanation.